# How can I put "AdaptiveActionSet" in "AdaptiveColumn"?

Tags: c#, json, botframework, adaptive-cards

I would like to put "AdaptiveOpenUrlAction" in "AdaptiveColumnSet" for a better layout of adaptivecards.
However, my bot emulator does not display the OpenUrl button.

How do I add an action button? Perhaps this is a problem with the version of adaptivecards? The version of my adaptivecards is 1.1 (1.0 is also available).
I would like to ask for a solution.

Below is the code I wrote and the json log I created in the emulator. The Json Log in the ActionSet is written to the emulator, but the buttons in the ActionSet are not displayed on the card.

C# Code

```
new AdaptiveColumn()
{
    Items =
    {
        new AdaptiveActionSet()
        {
            Actions =
            {
                new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction()
                {
                    Url = new Uri("https://www.someurl.com"),
                    Title = "Reserve",
                    Style = "positive",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Width = "auto",
}
```

JsonLog

```
"items": [
  {
    "actions": [
      {
        "style": "positive",
        "title": "Reserve",
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "url": "https://www.someurl.com"
      }
    ],
    "type": "ActionSet"
  }
],
"type": "Column",
"width": "auto"
```

Below is the layout of the adaptivecards I created from 'https://adaptivecards.io/designer/' I want.

```
{
    "type": "ColumnSet",
    "columns": [
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "width": "stretch",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "2019-09-10",
                    "spacing": "None",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                    "color": "Good",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                }
            ],
            "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "spacing": "None",
            "style": "emphasis",
            "bleed": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "width": "stretch",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "USD 100.00",
                    "spacing": "None",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                    "size": "Large",
                    "color": "Warning",
                    "weight": "Bolder"
                }
            ],
            "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
            "bleed": true,
            "style": "emphasis",
            "spacing": "None"
        },
        {
            "type": "Column",
            "width": "auto",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "title": "Reserve",
                            "style": "positive",
                            "url": "https://www.someurl.com"
                        }
                    ],
                    "spacing": "None"
                }
            ],
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "spacing": "None",
            "bleed": true,
            "style": "emphasis"
        }
    ],
    "spacing": "None",
    "separator": true
}
```

Comment: Have you taken the JSON from the emulator log and copied it into the adaptive card designer to see if it actually works?

Comment: Yes, I've pasted the Json log into 'adaptivecards.io/designer' and it works fine.

Comment: That's good then, means it's likely something to do with rendering on the simulator/device I.E. margins, or layout that's not inheriting correctly from it's parents.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So how do I solve it? How can I inherit correctly?

Comment: First I'd try setting the width yourself to see if the controls are being rendered outside of the view boundaries.

Comment: What channel is your bot intended for besides Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the schema that action sets were introduced in Adaptive Cards 1.2: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/ActionSet.html

[image]

The only official chat client that currently supports Adaptive Cards 1.2 is Web Chat, but Web Chat uses the Direct Line channel and Direct Line strips out elements it doesn't recognize: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/87

In that GitHub issue, you will find a workaround where you use a custom content type instead of `application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive`. If you set the content type to `application/vnd.microsoft.card.custom` for example, you can convert the attachment back into an Adaptive Card in Web Chat's attachment middleware:

```js
const attachmentMiddleware = () => next => card => {
  if (card.attachment.contentType === 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.custom'){
    card.attachment.contentType = 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive'
  }
  return next(card)
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  directLine,
  attachmentMiddleware
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Using the workaround described in that issue, I was able to render your column set successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But shamefully, I didn't fully understand your answer. I don't know much about "attachmentMiddleware" and "application / vnd.microsoft.card.custom". If you don't mind, can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: Did you read the GitHub issue I linked you to? Attachment middleware is a property of the object you pass into `renderWebChat`: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#web-chat-api-reference

Comment: You're asking for more help but you still haven't answered the question of what channel you're using

Comment: Oh Thanks, The channels I use are mostly web chat, and I plan to use Facebook, Skype, and Lines in addition. I will read through the documents you have provided.

Comment: Facebook, Skype, and Line do not support Adaptive Cards

Comment: I am writing webChat.html recently. However, I still don't know how to customize the adaptive card. I want to display a reservation button that shows up in the image you attached. If so, should I fix adaptiveCardHostConfig? Or should we fix the function that calls the card? I assigned 'application / vnd.microsoft.card.custom' to the contentType of my adaptivecard. And like your answer, I wrote attachmentMiddleware but it couldn't render the card.

Comment: And I referenced this link (https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2034#issuecomment-501818238)
I saw this and also created adaptiveCardHostConfig, but I'm not sure how to customize adaptive-cards. Can you help me once more?

Comment: Please leave a comment if you need the code I wrote

Comment: @SLock - First, you need to make up your mind about what you're trying to do. My answer has nothing to do with host configs. If you want to learn about host configs then you should ask a new question. If you want to learn about how to apply my answer then you need to explain exactly what you're doing and what's happening and what you're expected to happen, and you need to ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I registered a new question.