# How to customize Adaptive-Cards in WebChat?

Tags: c#, json, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

This question is an extension of my previous question.
([How can I put "AdaptiveActionSet" in "AdaptiveColumn"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141476/how-can-i-put-adaptiveactionset-in-adaptivecolumn))

At the time, I didn't know much about the customization of adaptive cards and the WebChat.html file.

[image: myCard1]

The image above is the layout of the adaptive card I want.
The Reserve button on the right is Action.OpenUrl button.

[image: myCard2]

To place a button like that, I need to put an ActionSet in a Column. However, typical Adaptive Cards do not show ActionSet in Column as in the image above.
The content type is shown below.
`ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"`
(In web chat)

To solve this, I have to customize Adaptive Cards, but I'm not sure how.

(Ashamed,
I referred to the link below but still I can't customize the card.

[Bot Connector service is not using latest Adaptive Cards #87](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/87#issuecomment-500662897)

Can you show me a way to solve this or show a simple customized card example? Please.

Below is the code I wrote.

My Adaptive Cards Code :

```
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveColumnSet()
{
    Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>()
    {
        new AdaptiveColumn()
        {
            //(~Date, No problem)
        },
        new AdaptiveColumn()
        {
            //(~Price, No problem)
        },
        new AdaptiveColumn()
        {
            Items =
            {
                new AdaptiveActionSet()
                {
                    Actions =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction()
                        {
                            Url = new Uri("https://www.SomeUrl.com"),
                            Title = "Reserve",
                            Style = "positive",
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            Width = "auto",
        }
    },
});

var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>
{
    new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.custom",
        Content = card
    }
};
```

My webChat.html :

```
const attachmentMiddleware = () => next => card => {
  if (card.attachment.contentype === 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.custom'){
    card.attachment.contentType = 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive'
  }
  return next(card)
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: botConnection,
    styleOptions,
    adaptiveCardHostConfig,
    attachmentMiddleware
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));

document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

As above, `ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.custom"`

If I assign custom to contentType,

[image: MyCard3]

I get an error called No renderer.

Comment: Can you update your images? It looks like links are broken.

Comment: @tdurnford - Oh Sorry, Do you see the image now?

Comment: Can you right-click the web page and view the page source to verify that you are using the code that you think you're using?

Comment: @ Kyle Delaney [webchat image](https://i.imgur.com/tx9hdWE.png) It exists but is not in the right condition.

Comment: What exists? What is that screenshot of? It looks like the card is rendering without the error that you showed in your question

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - I want the reserve button to appear in the div.ac-vertical-separator section of the screenshot.

Comment: And to display the screenshot, I assigned application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive to ContentType.

Comment: In Chrome, you can right click any page and select "View page source." This should reveal your full HTML including your JavaScript. When you do this, are you seeing the code you wrote with the attachment middleware?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - Yes, I can see the attachment  middleware code.This is the [image link](https://i.imgur.com/2djfUJr.png?1) in that code.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted in the question is from the Bot Emulator. Why did you post an Emulator screenshot if the problem Web Chat? Are you really encountering the problem in Web Chat or just when you're using Emulator?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - Yes, I'm getting the same error in emulator and webchat. And the top two of the screenshots are from 'https://adaptivecards.io/designer/' and the bottom one is from web chat.

Comment: The bottom one is absolutely from Emulator and not Web Chat because the "No renderer" error box is Emulator-specific. Please show a screenshot of that error in Web Chat that contains the whole browser page.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - I solved the problem yesterday. Using AdaptiveColumn's SelectAction solved the problem. I solved it by using AdaptiveTextBlock and SelectAction together and specifying Width. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Go ahead and post that as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AdaptiveColumn's SelectAction solved the problem. 
And it by using AdaptiveTextBlock and SelectAction together and specifying Width.

ex)

```
Items =
    {
        new AdaptiveTextBlock()
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Center,
            Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Light,
            Text = "Reserve",
            Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
         }
    },
    SelectAction = new AdaptiveOpenUrlAction()
    {
        Url = new Uri($"{someurl}"),
        Title = "rsv",
        Id = "bb" + cnt,
    },
    Width = "50px"
```